# Regex pattern for special condition

Tags: java, regex, jsf

Input field to hold alphabets, space, numbers, defined following regex

```
[a-zA-Z ]{1,150}
```

Need to include parenthesis and hyphen in above regex.

Kindly advise.

Comment: How are you using this? what language? what have you tried so far?

Comment: In JSF with <f:validateRegex pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ()-]{1,150}"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only tricky item is hyphen: it must not come between characters, because it has special interpretation. Put it in the first or in the last position, like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9 ()-]{1,150}
```

I added `0-9` because you said that you want to allow digits as well.

> Hyphen can be anywhere in the input

Note that the position of hyphen in the regex *character class* (the construct enclosed in square brackets) has nothing to do with the position of hyphen in the text being matched. The order of characters inside character class is not significant, except for two cases when a character has special interpretation: hyphen `-` between two characters defines a range, and `^` at the beginning defines negation.

Comment: Hi, For my requirement, hyphen can be anywhere in the input

Comment: @techie2k Regex does not consider the last hyphen special, because it parses the expression as `a-z` followed by `A-Z` followed by `-`, so there is no free-standing character ahead of the third hyphen. This is not very readable, though, so I would suggest moving the hyphen to a place where it wouldn't be confused for a separator of two sides of a character range.